# PyCharm: execute in Python console

Tags: python, pycharm, program-entry-point

I'm working on a Python project in PyCharm. For one file I would like to test parts of the code using the Python console. Problem is that the code contains a main method (used for debugging and execution) like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("with main")
else:
    print("no main")
```

When I execute that code in the Python Console (using context menu of PyCharm) then the first part of the if will be executed. I was expecting the else-part since I'm not starting the script using a Run-configuration.

Maybe you can help me how to do that.

Comment: But that is exactly what you would want running in the python console, right? It behaves exactly like program. Why do you not like it?

Comment: Yes and no. If I start the script from the shell or via the run-configuration of PyCharm then I'm adding arguments that I then extract and handle in the if-part. But if I want to test the script in the console, then I have no way to specify command line arguments. That's why I would add default values to the else-part.

Comment: Good point... I never had this issue. If it worked it would have been a good solution...

Answer (score 1):

Create file like `not_main_start.py` with only one line `import main.py` (I guess this is your main file). Run then this file. Output should show `no main`. `__name__` would be name `__main__` only if you call this file directly. If you use it as module then it will have name of the module.

Comment: Interesting idea. But finally you want to parse the command line arguments in the main file and then invoke methods of the other file. So your import is the other way around.